# Total Count in SQL for CourseList Table

Tags: sql

I am having an issue counting the algebra I courses from my table.

I would like to show columns `SchoolID` `Alg1` and leave the `Section_Number` off, i.e.:

```
110      14
```

Here is my code and I have attached an image of my output:

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT
  cc.SchoolID
 ,e.alg1
 ,cc.Section_Number
FROM
  dbo.CRDC_2017_Course_Enrollments AS e
LEFT JOIN
  PSExtracts.PS_SCS_CC_Export AS cc
    ON
    e.StudentID = cc.StudentID
WHERE
  e.alg1 NOT LIKE 'NULL'
  AND (CONVERT(DATE, cc.DateEnrolled, 120) <= '2017-10-01')
  AND (CONVERT(DATE, cc.DateLeft, 120) >= '2017-10-01')
GROUP BY
  cc.SchoolID
 ,e.alg1
 ,cc.Section_Number;
```

[image: CourseList]

Comment: Then remove `Section_Number` from your `SELECT` column list.

Comment: Here are my results from my query  but, I only want to show a school id and a count of the different sections per class    like School Id = 10 and Class Count = 7                                                                                                                 SchoolID alg1                       Section_Number  
10        Algebra I 08 Hon 1
10        Algebra I 08 Hon 3
10        Algebra I 08 Hon 4
10        Algebra I 08 Hon 7
10        Algebra I 08 Hon 6
10        Algebra I 08 Hon 2
10        Algebra I 08 Hon 5

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your criteria for excluding null values:

```
e.alg1 not like 'NULL'
```

Should be:

```
e.alg1 is not null
```

As a null value is not equal to the string `'null'`

---

The rest of your questions isn't entirely clear, but perhaps the following is what you are looking to achieve:

```
select cc.SchoolID, Count(e.alg1)
from 
    dbo.CRDC_2017_Course_Enrollments e left join PSExtracts.PS_SCS_CC_Export cc
    on e.StudentID = cc.StudentID 
where
    e.alg1 is not null
    and 
    (CONVERT(date, cc.DateEnrolled, 120) <= '2017-10-01') AND 
    (CONVERT(date, cc.DateLeft, 120) >= '2017-10-01') 
group by    
    cc.SchoolID
```